# How to add primereact to laravel with react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, primereact

I have a laravel 8 app with laravel/ui installed and react preset. I want to use primereact for the react spa, but I don't know how to add to laravel mix etc, Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, Laravel put some files on resources folder, you have to edit app.scss and add to the end this lines

```css
@import 'primereact/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css';
@import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';
@import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

Of course you can change the theme css

Also you have to run these commands

npm install primereact --save
npm install primeicons --save

And into your components you can import your prime's component that you want.

Example:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//PRIMENG
import { Menubar } from 'primereact/menubar';
import { InputText } from 'primereact/inputtext';

export class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.items = [
            {
                label: 'File',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'New',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus',
                        items: [
                            {
                                label: 'Bookmark',
                                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark'
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'Video',
                                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-video'
                            },

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Delete',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'
                    },
                    {
                        separator: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Export',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-external-link'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Edit',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'Left',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-left'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Right',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-right'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Center',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-center'
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Justify',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-align-justify'
                    },

                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Users',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'New',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-plus',

                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Delete',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-minus',

                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Search',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-users',
                        items: [
                            {
                                label: 'Filter',
                                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-filter',
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        label: 'Print',
                                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-print'
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bars',
                                label: 'List'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Events',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar',
                items: [
                    {
                        label: 'Edit',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
                        items: [
                            {
                                label: 'Save',
                                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-plus'
                            },
                            {
                                label: 'Delete',
                                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-minus'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Archieve',
                        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-times',
                        items: [
                            {
                                label: 'Remove',
                                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-calendar-minus'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Quit',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-power-off'
            }
        ];
    }

    render() {
        const start = <img alt="logo" src="showcase/images/logo.png" onError={(e) => e.target.src='https://www.primefaces.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/placeholder.png'} height="40" className="p-mr-2"></img>;
        const end = <InputText placeholder="Search" type="text" />;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="card">
                    <Menubar model={this.items} start={start} end={end} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```